# Simple line graph - Dynamically resizing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was working with the d3.js [simple line graph](http://bl.ocks.org/2579599) example and was wondering how to dynamically adjust the domain for the x and y axis so that if the data is updated, the graph can be adjusted to fit the new line. here is the current code (I think) that sets these domains.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([-15, 15]).range([0, w]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 120]).range([h, 0]);
```

Currently the domain values are arbitrary. the vairables w and h are the width and the height of the svg element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by setting the lower and upper bounds of your domain to dynamic values, calculated from your data set.  Depending on the structure or your data, d3 has `max` and `min` methods that will calculate the max / min values in an array of values.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]).range([0,w]);
```

If you have some method to update your data, you can add functionality to then redefine `x` (you might want to attach `x` to some sort of namespace that is accessible throughout the entire scope of your function) and then recall your line generator (via `d3.svg.line()`).

#### UPDATE

Seeing your comments, let me clarify.

There are several different ways that you can do this, since d3 is such a low-level library (which I personally think is part of the appeal).  In my own work, I use multiple series which conveniently allows me to use the common *enter, update and exit* model that you see used with other chart types (like a bar chart).  But in the most basic terms, here's what you need:

1. You'll need to initially setup a couple objects:

   - your SVG container
   - your x and y scales
   - a line generator, not bound to any data
2. Next, you'll use that line generator to initialize an `SVG:path` element with your dataset
3. Then you'll need to create a means up updating your `SVG:path` element and scales with new data

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbeasley183/DbXhL/) that demonstrates this, adding new random data every seconds for 10 seconds.

Comment: I understand that you can set the range using the min and max methods, but I was wondering how exactly to updated the graph when the data is updated. I was just giving those values as an example. My question is that lets say the default data has a max of 120 and a min of 50. Then the user updates the data and the max becomes 200 and a min of 80. how do we make the y axis reflect that  change without deleting the graph and recreating it with the new min and max? Sorry for being unclear earlier.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do dynamically adjust the x and y axis as well? For example, if the Y range was 0-20 and it changes to 0-35, how would you transition it to the new scale? Ive tried multiple things, but none worked, so I ended up having to temporarily make it delete the original graph and create a completely new one.

Comment: @user1410270 I'd post a new question.